# c# sql command premeter crashing

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, sqlcommand

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code?
The data source is good and it is showing me the same mistake each time:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DatabaseActions
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void AddUser(string firstname, string lastname, string username, string password, string password2, string email, string location, string birthday, string gender)
        {
            string connectionstring = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=GedgetsDB";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            connection.Open();
            string insert1 = "INSERT INTO TBL_Users(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, Password2, Email, Location, Birthday, Gender)";
            string insert2 = "VALUES ('" + firstname + "' , '" + lastname + "' , '" + username + "' , '" + password + "' , '" + password2 + "' , '" + email + "' , '" + location + "' , '" + birthday + "' , '" + gender+"')";
            string Insertcommandtext = insert1 + insert2;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Insertcommandtext, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter firstname: ");
            string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter lastname: ");
            string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter password2: ");
            string password2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter email: ");
            string email = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter location: ");
            string location = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter birthday: ");
            string birthday = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter gender: ");
            string gender = Console.ReadLine();
            AddUser(firstname, lastname, username, password, password2, email, location, birthday, gender);

        }
    }
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot open database "GedgetsDB" requested by
>   the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'AMITPC\עמית'.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please, consider next time to post code as it is without links to other resources than SO.

Comment: I suppose you are using windows integrated authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the database and ensure your login 'AMITPC\עמית' has access to the database you are trying to open.
If the login has access check if your application is directed to the right database in your config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server you need to actually create a login for the mentioned user or edit your connection string to specify the `User ID` and `pwd`.